# Is it possible to dynamically create variables in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, uitableview

I'm working on an app and the client has asked if it would be possible to architect the app so the forms within the app could change dynamically based on their need changing only the web service responses. I'm thinking something similar to variable variables in PHP.

```
    [{
        "field_item_2": "abc",
        "field_item_3": "123",
        "field_item_4": "test answer",
        "field_item_5": "",
        "field_item_6": 100,
        "field_item_7": 1,
        "comments": "Comments go here.",
        "users": "John Smith, Jane Doe, Tim Johnson",
```

Currently I've got it setup with a set number of properties to match web service values, but this will not scale easily and ideally I'd like to be able to get the tableview setup dynamically based upon the web service response

```
    "complex_data_1": [{
        "cd1_format": "textfield",
        "cd1_format_id": 12,
        "cd1_question": "What is your favorite color",
        "cd1_answer": ""
    }],
    "complex_data_2": [{
        "cd2_format": "textfield",
        "cd2_format_id": 12,
        "cd2_question": "What is your favorite car",
        "cd3_answer": ""
    }],
    "complex_data3": [{
        "cd3_format": "datePicker",
        "cd3_format_id": 10,
        "cd3_question": "What is your birthdate",
        "cd3_answer": ""
    }]
}]
```

To try to be more concise, for a given view controller where I can can populate a UITableView with n rows in size containing an unknown array of custom cells* -- is it possible to create variables/properties to accurately record data for that UI and save/send it back to the server, where the variables for the datasource are created when the web service response is returned?

*number of table rows and type of UITableViewCells can be sent back and displayed already from data in web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not only possible, it's kind of unavoidable.  You'll be turning that JSON into an array of dictionaries, and each dictionary will describe a `UIControl` in your custom cell.  Think of that array as your table's datasource.

There's one more object *required* to describe a UIControl, and that's it's *value*.  Make the dictionary mutable (which is an option when parsing the JSON, "mutableContainers") and add one additional key to the dictionary, call it, say, `@"value"`.

The custom cells you make will be the delegates of the controls you add dynamically, and when they detect that their controls' value's change, they will update the `dictionary[@"value"]`

Answer (score 0):

I love the library [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm) for things like this.

Dynamically create forms.
You could create a 1-1 mapping between the field types in your web service response to XLForm rowType